# Jinja2 shorthand conditional

Tags: python, jinja2, conditional-operator

Say I have this:

```
{% if files %}
    Update
{% else %}
    Continue
{% endif %}
```

In PHP, say, I can write a shorthand conditional, like:

```php
<?php echo $foo ? 'yes' : 'no'; ?>
```

Is there then a way I can translate this to work in a jinja2 template:

```
'yes' if foo else 'no'
```

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but the php expression looks a lot like what is called the "ternary operator" in C-like languages.  The final line is called the "conditional expression" in python, although I've seen it called the ternary operator in python as well.  Anyway, I mention it as it might help to know the names of those things in a google search.

Answer (score 555, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to use [inline if-expressions](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#if-expression):

```
{{ 'Update' if files else 'Continue' }}
```

Comment: A shorthand for `{{ value if value else 'No value' }}` would be `{{ value or 'No value' }}`

Comment: @DorinGrecu My code is not full with `{{ tobe or 'Not to be' }}` thanks to you :)

Comment: If you need to use a variable, you can use inside `{% %}` too.
Like `{% set your_var = 'Update' if files else 'Continue'  %}`

Comment: can it also contain markup like: {{ '<h4>Update</h4>' if files else '<h4>Continue</h4>' }}?

Comment: @Macilias depends on how `autoescape` is configured. If it's set to `True`, you may need to add the `| safe` filter.

Comment: What to do in following condition `{{ "Whoops" if message.tags == 'danger' else message.tags }}`

Comment: @DonGrem Warning: suppose `value` is `None`. In that case, the Jinja expression `{{ value or 'No value' }}` will return `None`

Answer (score 11):

Alternative way (but it's not python style. It's JS style)

```
{{ files and 'Update' or 'Continue' }}
```

Comment: This construct is not really applicable in languages that interpret an empty string as falsy. `True and '' or 'a'` will evaluate to `a`, which is not what was intended.