# Jinja table, when column == value then add div to specific column

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

I have a flask app with a jinja table, one of the columns has the value = 1 when that row meets a criteria.

For every row that a 1 is present in that column i would like to replace it with a circle, for example:

[image]

How would I add it to my jinja table?

```
<table>
        <thead>

          <tr>
            {% for col in column_names %}
            <th>
            
              {{col}}
             
            </th>
            {% endfor %}
          </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% for row in row_data %}
          <tr>
            {% for col, row_ in zip(column_names, row) %}

  {% if loop.index == 1 %} 
            <td> 

IF  {{ row[16] }} == 1 then <div class="circle" style="float: left;">LB</div> 
else ''
end 

 {{row_}}</td>
{% else %}
            <td>{{row_}}</td>

 {% endif %}

            {% endfor %}
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}

         
        </tbody>
  
      </table>
```

HTML/CSS code of div i want to appear in that cell

```
.circle
    {
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    border-radius:10px;
    font-size:8px;
    color:#fff;
    line-height:20px;
    text-align:center;
    background:#000
    }

<div class="circle" style="float: left;">LB</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

Try the following.

> The one-line `if-else` statement in `jinja2` looks like this:
>
> ```
> {{ OUTPUT_WHEN_TRUE if condition else OUTPUT_WHEN_FLASE }}
> ```
>
> So, in your case, the code within for each `<td></td>` (where `loop.index == 1` over the inner loop) will look like this:
>
> ```
> {{ '<div class="circle" style="float: left;">LB</div>' if row[16] == 1 else '' }} {{ row_ }}
> ```

[image: Open in Colab]

### Code

```
<table>
    <thead>

        <tr>
        {% for col in column_names %}
        <th>
        
            {{col}}
            
        </th>
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for row in row_data %}
        {% set row_loop = loop %}
        <tr>
        {% for col, row_ in zip(column_names, row) %}
        {% set col_loop = loop %}

        {# Choose which loop: row or col you are referring to #} 
        {% if col_loop.index == 1 %} 
        <td> 

            {{ '<div class="circle" style="float: left;">LB</div>' if row[16] == 1 else '' }} {{ row_ }}

        </td>
        {% else %}
            
            <td>{{ row_ }}</td>

        {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
     
    </tbody>
  
</table>
```

### References

- [Get loop index of outer loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567291/get-loop-index-of-outer-loop)
- [Jinja Docs - *Accessing the parent Loop*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/tricks/#accessing-the-parent-loop)
- [Jinja shorthand conditional: *one-line `if-else`*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14214942/jinja2-shorthand-conditional)

Comment: I'm getting a ```jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: tag name expected``` error

Comment: @mikelowry Have you tested the rest of your code already? Was it working without the `<div class="circle...>LB</div>` part?

Comment: Yes it works until i add ```{% '<div class="circle" style="float: left;">LB</div>' if row[16] == 1 else '' %} {{ row_ }} ```

Comment: So i got it to work using ```         {% if  row[16] == '1' %}
              <div class="circle" style="float: left;">LB</div>

              {% else %}
            
              {% endif %}
``` Thank you! You led me in the right direction!

Comment: Great! I just realized that my answer had a typo. One line `if-else` requires `{{ ... }}` instead of `{% ... %}`.